# Experiencing random text distortion Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, graphics, text

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu on a brand new Dell Latitude E5470. Today I have noticed a really annoying random text distortion happening on unrelated pages. I have attached a screenshot of an example of this effect. I have not come across any mentions or fixes of this issue. Rebooting does not fix it and I have no idea what else to try.

Text artifacts:

[image: Text artifacts]

Any ideas?

Comment: The site in your example requires a password to access. Is the issue occurring on any other sites?

Comment: Yes, this happens on any site at any time, this was just a time I was able to catch it. If I scroll up or down the issue goes away, only tom come back in aanother random spot at any given time.